# Matrices inside a table

Tags: tables

I am trying to fit two-by-two matrices inside a table along with figures. An error stems from the matrix part. I would appreciate it if you could help me.

```
\documentclass{standalone}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace} \doublespacing
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow,}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
\textbf{A}     &   \textbf{B}  &   \textbf{C}  \\
\midrule  

$\begin{pmatrix}  \ast & \ast \\ \ast &  \ast \end{pmatrix}$ 
&
$\begin{pmatrix}  \ast & \ast \\ \ast &  \ast \end{pmatrix}$
&
$\begin{pmatrix}  \ast & \ast \\ \ast &  \ast \end{pmatrix}$

\midrule
\includegraphics[width=30mm,height=15mm,valign=m]{example-image-a}  &  
\includegraphics[width=30mm,height=15mm,valign=m]{example-image-a} & 
\includegraphics[width=30mm,height=15mm,valign=m]{example-image-a}  
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your error is simply a missing `\\ ` before `\midrule`, unrelated to the matrix

Comment: ! Misplaced \noalign.
\midrule ->\noalign 
                    {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\aboverulesep \global \@...
l.21 \midrule
             
?

Comment: Mr. Carlisle thank you so much. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is simply a missing `\\`  before `\midrule`, unrelated to the matrix.